# Auto populate slash in matdatepicker text field on keyup

Tags: angular, angular-material

Currently we are using angular 8, angular material, .netcore2.2

When ever user starts to enter date in text field(in my case matdatepicker field), It should auto populate slash i.e for example if user enter date in any format like ddmmyy or mmddyy, then slash should be populate right after user enters dd/ or mm/(in other words a slash should populate after dd or mm which looks like (dd/ or mm/) (dd/mm/ or mm/dd/))and **this should happen to all matdatepickers fields in my application**.Please suggest me a better way to implement above requirement.Below sample code for one of the datepicker field.

```
<mat-form-field class="mat-input-field">
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="AssessmentDate" placeholder="Assessment Begin Date*"
                   formControlName="aO_ASSESS_BEGIN_DATE" aria-label="Date" ng-keyup="">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="AssessmentDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #AssessmentDate></mat-datepicker>
            <mat-hint align="start"><strong>Format mm/dd/yyyy</strong> </mat-hint>
            <mat-error *ngIf="sectionAForm.get('aO_ASSESS_BEGIN_DATE').errors?.required || sectionAForm.get('aO_ASSESS_BEGIN_DATE').errors?.matDatepickerParse">Assessment Date Required (mm/dd/yyyy)</mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="sectionAForm.get('aO_ASSESS_BEGIN_DATE').errors?.futureDate">Assessment Date cannot be future.</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with the help of `angular2-text-mask`

Visits: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-text-mask?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

After, successful installation, and importing of this package, do the below steps

Step:1 in your `component.ts` file add this line:

```
public datemask = [ /[1-9]/, /\d/,'/', /\d/, /\d/, '/', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/];
```

Step:2 In your `component.html` file add the below lines:

```
<mat-form-field class="input">
    <input matInput [textMask]="{mask: datemask }" [matDatepicker]="picker" #input>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```